# How to split a string using "-" keyword ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

This is My string i like to split it using special character "-"

```
hi - नमस्ते
Hindi - हिन्दी
Telugu - तेलुगु
how - कैसे
are - हैं
you - आप
go - जाना
going - जा रहा
translate - अनुवाद करना
good - अच्छा
```

What i was tried :

```
[strFileContent enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, strFileContent.length)
                                               options:NSStringEnumerationByWords
                                            usingBlock:
             ^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                 checking=substring;
                 NSLog(@"this is my splitting values =%@",substring);

             }];
```

If i did above method each word getting separately so that continues words getting brakes for eg translate - अनुवाद **करना** this word getting brakes .

2)`[arrcheck addObject:[strFileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]];`

if i did 2 method then \n getting added

```
"Tamil ",
        " \U0924\U093e\U092e\U093f\U0932
\nhi ",
        " \U0928\U092e\U0938\U094d\U0924\U0947
\nHindi ",
        " \U0939\U093f\U0928\U094d\U0926\U0940
\nTelugu ",
        " \U0924\U0947\U0932\U0941\U0917\U0941
\nhow ",
        " \U0915\U0948\U0938\U0947
\nare ",
        " \U0939\U0948\U0902
\nyou ",
        " \U0906\U092a
\ngo ",
        " \U091c\U093e\U0928\U093e
\ngoing ",
        " \U091c\U093e \U0930\U0939\U093e
\ntranslate ",
        " \U0905\U0928\U0941\U0935\U093e\U0926 \U0915\U0930\U0928\U093e
```

What is the exact way to get values separately.

Comment: have you checked componentsSeparatedByString method for string ???

Comment: what your string contains initially?

Comment: @SuhasPatil my srting containing this values hi - नमस्ते
Hindi - हिन्दी
Telugu - तेलुगु
how - कैसे
are - हैं
you - आप
go - जाना
going - जा रहा
translate - अनुवाद करना
good - अच्छा

Comment: Ok, and you want to split the english separately and hindi separately?

Comment: thanks @SuhasPatil :)

Comment: Don't write the data to file like this.  Use a `.plist` instead or the normal Apple internationalisation framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// ORIGINAL STRING:    NSString *hindi = @"hi - नमस्ते Hindi - हिन्दी Telugu - तेलुगु how - कैसे are - हैं you - आप go - जाना going - जा रहा translate - अनुवाद करना good - अच्छा";
```

-

```
NSString *hindi = @"hi - नमस्ते Hindi - हिन्दी Telugu - तेलुगु how - कैसे are - हैं you - आप go - जाना going - जारहा translate - अनुवादकरना good - अच्छा";


hindi = [hindi stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"- " withString:@""];

NSArray *mixArray = [hindi componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"mixArray: %@",mixArray);


NSMutableArray *arrayForEnglishWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i =0 ; i < mixArray.count; i++) {

    if(i%2 == 0){

        [arrayForEnglishWords addObject:mixArray[i]];
    }
}


for (NSString *str in arrayForEnglishWords) {

        NSLog(@": %@",str);

}

NSLog(@"__________________");

NSMutableArray *arrayForHindiWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i =0 ; i < mixArray.count; i++) {

    if(i%2 != 0){

        [arrayForHindiWords addObject:mixArray[i]];
    }
}

for (NSString *str in arrayForHindiWords) {

    NSLog(@": %@",str);

}
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

-

> I have removed the spacing between the hindi words because that's
>   disturbing the logic, any how if you will able to put the different
>   separator between words
>   Eg: if you used "," as separator then you
>   will string will become as
>    NSString *hindi = @"hi - नमस्ते,Hindi -
>   हिन्दी,Telugu - तेलुगु,how - कैसे,are - हैं,you - आप,go - जाना,going-
>   जा रहा,translate - अनुवाद करना,good - अच्छा";
>
> then replace logic in above code as:
>
> hindi = [hindi stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"- " withString:@","];
>
> NSArray *mixArray = [hindi componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Comment: i think you can also use the "\n" as separator since your having that, check it!

Answer (score 0):

what I have tried with your string just check

```
NSString *hindi = @"hi - नमस्ते Hindi - हिन्दी Telugu - तेलुगु how - कैसे are - हैं you - आप go - जाना going - जा रहाtranslate - अनुवाद करना good - अच्छा";

NSArray *separr = [hindi componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

Try like this with your string.

If you are getting \n then remove it from array by checking the NSCharacterSet

Comment: you can remove \n character by with NSCharacterSet newline characters \

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input contains newline after each translation.

Try separating them using :

```
NSArray* components = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *finalComponents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString* strToken in components) {
    [finalComponents addObject:[strToken componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "]];
}
```